# Lenovo legion y520 not registering mic

Tags: windows-10, microphone

i recently bought a new laptop (Lenovo Legion y520) and i am having problems with my headset. ( steelseries sebaria v2 )

my headset has 2 cabels to put in the computer one for the mic and one for audio,
but my laptop only has 1 input jack.

I tried using an other headset with 1 cabel, it also has a mic and it cant find that mic either

pls help me i am not that good with computers ....

Answer (score 0):

#### But my laptop only has 1 input jack.

You need to talk to Lenovo as their own website and documentation contains conflicting information.

From their website:

[image]

You can see it clearly says:

> - Audio Jack
> - Microphone Jack

Source [Lenovo Legion Y520 Laptop](http://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/lenovo-legion-y-series-laptops/Lenovo-Y520-15IKBN/p/88GMY500808)

From the user manual:

Source [Lenovo Y520 Y520-15IKBN User Guide](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/legion_y520-15ikbn_ug_en_201701.pdf)

[image]

You can see it clearly says:

> Combo audio jack Connects to headsets.
>
> Notes:
>
> - The combo audio jack does not support conventional microphones.
> - The recording function might not be supported if third-party headphones or headsets are connected, due to different industry
>     standards.

Answer (score 0):

you will need some thing like that 
[audio jack adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Sennheiser-PCV-05-Combo-Audio-Adapter/122517708991?_trksid=p2045573.c100033.m2042&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D43550%26meid%3Dbbbf14c63bec49a2b8afe1a26c6ff8d8%26pid%3D100033%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26sd%3D122517708991)
but better use Bluetooth headphones , no one use these ancient headphones any more